# New Profile Design

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-planned

It seems like many of the other Stack Exchanges have adopted the new profile design ( [Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), [etc.](http://stackexchange.com/sites) I think it's a pretty cool design and was wondering why we're still using the old profile. Any chance we can upgrade to the new profile prototype?

Comment: There are many cool data sections available in the new profile layout, but I must admit I find some parts very confusing and hard to focus on, like the new "Top tags" section.

Comment: I agree with @birgire here. Although some features are nice, I'm not very fond of it. On mobiles it just don't work out unfortunately. My opinion is, keep our old dinosaur profile pages until everything is sorted with the new system :-)

Comment: @birgire I'm curious to hear more about what you find confusing in the new profile layout. If you'd like to chat, my email is in my profile (I work here).

Comment: @PieterGoosen Same as above — curious to hear more.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco the personal info section is missing on mobiles, the profile tab is missing important info which is quite obvious when you visit and compare your personal page on SO and WPSE from a mobile device. The mobile section, in my opinion took a downgrade. Also as birgire already pointed out, the top tags section is a bit scrambled and quite overwhelming on mobile devices, and then the rarest badge section does not make sense. Apart from that, the overall feel on large screen devices is not bad. As I said, my major issue is with mobile devices

Comment: Thanks @PieterGoosen, this is helpful.

Comment: My pleasure and good luck with this new feature :-) @ThomasOrozco

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Many good things in the new layout, but regarding the "Top Tags", I think it's the different layout in each line, tiny font and the whitespace usage there. This section is also missing the main title underline, like the other sections have. Here the tags are in different style than in the "Badges" section. Many users don't write profile description, so there's lot of white space in the center. The "Top Meta Posts" has different type of counting than the other sections that use parentheses. The word "posts" comes up a lot, but it's not clear at first, if that's Q, A, or both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For us (Stack Exchange) to enable the new profile on Wordpress.SE, we first need to complete CSS updates, which require a bit of design work.

This old-ish announcement explains this in more detail: [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list).

And, you can see the the list of sites that have yet to be converted here (which as you can see includes Wordpress.SE):  [List of communities with base css updates completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed).